# Function Play/Stop - GalleryView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using the plug in called GalleryView (http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview/) and I want to find a way to make a function to pause the gallery when I want.

I use some Ajax requests to call images from a calendar in determinates days, if a play the gallery in the day 1 and click in the day 2, the gallery don't stop.

In the js file of the plug have the code bellow that I think stops the gallery, but I don't know how do access it from my content page:

```
stopSlideshow: function(changeIcon) {
        var self = this,
            dom = this.dom;

        if(changeIcon) {
            dom.gv_navPlay.removeClass('gv_navPause').addClass('gv_navPlay');
        }
        this.playing = false;
        dom.gv_galleryWrap.stopTime('slideshow_'+this.id);
    },
```

Thanks.

Comment: The page you linked to shows an option called `enable_slideshow` which is `flag to toggle play/pause button and ability to start/stop slideshow`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: My page is exactly like the demo, I just put a calendar in the top to call the images. The page already have a play/pause buttom from the plug in. What I want is to create a function to handle the play/stop event.